# Detect shift of pattern between two 2D matrices

Tags: matrix, pattern-recognition, lags

I have 2D matrices reflecting a time-space array (i.e. population densities in along spatially adjacent samplings (1D-space) and over multiple time steps). Specifically, I have two matrices of the same shape (same dimensions) one representing observed patterns and the other one modelled patterns of populations densities. Now, I'd like to compare both matrices for differences. Here I could calculate cell-based differences etc. But I am specifically interested if there is a shift of the pattern in time or space (i.e. in x or y - direction).

Here I provide some sample R-code the could represent my two matrices based on a sine function and with a shift in both axis:

```
X_Space <- 1:50
Y_Time <- 1:50

ar_results_1 <- array(NA,
                    dim=c(length(X_Space),length(Y_Time)))
ar_results_2 <- ar_results_1
for(x in X_Space){
  for(y in Y_Time){
      ar_results_1[x,y] <- sin(x*100)+sin(y*150)
      ar_results_2[x,y] <- sin((x+2)*100)+sin((y+2)*150)
    }
}

par(mfrow=c(2,1),mar=c(2,2,1.5,1.5))
image(ar_results_2)
image(ar_results_1)
```

What are common (statistical) methods to detect potential shifts of patterns, either locally (i.e. in parts of the matrix) or globally (over the entire matrix as in the example)?

Answer (score 1):

One distance measure between matrices and histograms I like is the [Earth Mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover's_distance). It essentially measures how much mass you have to shift *at minimum* between cells in the first matrix to turn it into the second matrix.

The same can be done in one-dimensional distributions, so you could apply it row-by-row or column-by-column or to the marginals of your matrices.

In R, you can use the [`emdist` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emdist). Unfortunately, `emd2d(ar_results_1,ar_results_2)` returns -24.7, which doesn't appear helpful, and says that it has reached its maximum number of iterations, but you may be able to follow up on this.